# Javascript "member not found"

Tags: javascript

I have a web page that has some links to pdf files that open in a new scrren.  If I click one of the links the new page opens fine.  If I click on another link while that page is open it replaces the page with the new page which is fine, however it throws a JS erre saying  "member not found"

HTML:

```
helpMenu.add( new AnchorMenuItem("User Guide", "javascript:openHelpWindow('../html/help/user_guide.html');") );
helpMenu.add( new AnchorMenuItem("FAQ", "javascript:openHelpWindow('../html/help/faq.html');") );
helpMenu.add( new AnchorMenuItem("Features", "javascript:openHelpWindow('../html/help/features.html');") );
helpMenu.add( new AnchorMenuItem("Overview", "javascript:openHelpWindow('../doc/Overview.pdf');") );
helpMenu.add( new AnchorMenuItem("Actual Info Guide", "javascript:openHelpWindow('../doc/ActualInfoGuide.pdf');") );
```

JS

```
/**
* Function to open the pop-up windows that the radio button
 * or select box options will be chosen from.
 */
function openHelpWindow(url)
{
    var w;
    if (isBrowserNetscape)
    {
        // Netscape
        w = window.open(url, "MSSTHelp", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, menubar=no, location=no, toolbar=no, height=700, width=900, screenX=100, screenY=100");
    }
    else
    {
        // IE
        w = window.open(url, "MSSTHelp", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, menubar=no, location=no, toolbar=no, height=700, width=900, left=100, top=100");
    }
    w.focus();
}
```

The error is at `w.focus();`

Comment: Can we have a jsfiddle link ?

Comment: The `focus()` function isn't standard, maybe the browser you're testing on doesn't support it. If you want fine control over popups, it's probably better to use DHTML. For "help" popups, I personally strongly favour just opening a new tab with `target="_blank"`. That way the new window/tab will focus by default, and won't if the user chooses to do so using the browser's "open in background" feature. Links that replace the content of a previous popup window are also annoying. It'

Comment: Of course it is supported, but only if the window exist. Anyway 1997 called and want its JavaScript back.

Comment: Also, `href="javascript:…"` is terrible and you should never use it. `href` should point at documents or '#' for "nothing", if you want to alter the behaviour of links attach these alternations externally. Links that replace the content of a previous popup window are also annoying. It's an *advantage* (for the users) that the browser isn't a window manager – don't take this control away.

Comment: I suggest moving the "var w;" out of the function to a global scope and then testing whether the window before opening it and closing if it is open before re-opening and setting focus.

Comment: Millimose: the javascript: pseudoprotocol is necessary in this ancient menu script since it sets the href to the parameter passed. A better idea was to find a menu from 2012 instead of 1997

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions....

Answer (score 2):

Horribly old code. And would have failed in the browsers it was written for due to the spaces in the parms. Here is the documentation [window.open Best practices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.open#Best_practices)
There is no need to differentiate on the top/left and screenX,screenY - the latter being Netscape 4 and earlier and can be specified if you wish for the other browsers too since they will ignore the parameters they do not need. Any parm=no can be removed and any parm=yes can be set as just parm:

**Simple version:**

```
function openHelpWindow(url) {
   var w = window.open(url, "MSSTHelp", 
       "resizable,scrollbars,height=700,width=900,screenX=100,screenY=100,left=100,top=100");
   if (w) w.focus();
}
```

---

**Reusing already open window** according to the above documentation

```
var w; // global var
function openHelpWindow(url) {
   if (!w || w.closed) {
     w = window.open(url, "MSSTHelp",
        "resizable,scrollbars,height=700,width=900,screenX=100,screenY=100,left=100,top=100");
   }
   else {
     w.location=url; // OR window.open(url, "MSSTHelp"); 
   }
   if (w) w.focus();
}
```

Comment: Thanks...should I just jQuery?....I normally dont work on JS but this landed in my lap

Comment: jQuery will not make ANY difference. There is nothing in your code that would benefit from jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the scope of your "w" variable is inside the function you declared it within.

In order to make it accessible on the next call, you need to declare your w var outside the function. When you call the function, it makes a new box /inside/ the function called "w" that it sticks the reference to the window you create with window.open(). Then, when the function finishes executing, it throws that "w" away. Declaring "w" outside of the scope of the function is /better/, but can still be problematic (as now you're in global scope).

```
var w = null;
/**
* Function to open the pop-up windows that the radio button
* or select box options will be chosen from.
*/
function openHelpWindow(url)
{
    if (isBrowserNetscape)
    {
        // Netscape
        w = window.open(url, "MSSTHelp", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, menubar=no, location=no, toolbar=no, height=700, width=900, screenX=100, screenY=100");
    }
    else
    {
        // IE
        w = window.open(url, "MSSTHelp", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, menubar=no, location=no, toolbar=no, height=700, width=900, left=100, top=100");
    }
    w.focus();
}
```

Even this is not terribly efficient, as if the window is still open, you're forcing a rebuild of the whole window for each call, when you could simply tell the window you opened in the first place to go to the new url.

```
var w = null;
/**
* Function to open the pop-up windows that the radio button
* or select box options will be chosen from.
*/
function openHelpWindow(url)
{
    if(w == null){
        if (isBrowserNetscape)
        {
            // Netscape
            w = window.open(url, "MSSTHelp", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, menubar=no, location=no, toolbar=no, height=700, width=900, screenX=100, screenY=100");
        }
        else
        {
            // IE
            w = window.open(url, "MSSTHelp", "resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, menubar=no, location=no, toolbar=no, height=700, width=900, left=100, top=100");
        }
    } else {
        w.document.location(url);
        w.focus();
    }
}
```

STILL not efficient! Look at all that code duplication!

```
var w = null;
/**
* Function to open the pop-up windows that the radio button
* or select box options will be chosen from.
*/
function openHelpWindow(url)
{
    if(w == null){
        var winSpecs = "resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no," 
                     + "location=no,toolbar=no,height=700,width=900,"
                     + (isBrowserNetscape) ? "screenX=100,screenY=100" : "left=100,top=100";
        w = window.open(url, "MSSTHelp", winSpecs);
    } else {
        w.location(url);
        w.focus();
    }
}
```

Now, note, even in this refactored code, we have an issue... are you sure that all browsers other than Netscape use "left" and "top" when opening windows like this? Beyond that, there's even the issue of usability, and browser-based pop-up blockers, which might interfere with your code's function.

Comment: to be compatible with older browsers you will need to remove the spaces in the parms. Also document.location is deprecated and you should use window.location to write and document.URL to read it

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info... it's been so long since I've even bothered with window.open() that I have forgotten some of the fun little cross-browser issues with it! :)